# Importing Data from txt file to Oracle database

Tags: sql, sql-loader

Senario -There are 2000 records in a .txt file and 3 columns (Name, Phone Num, City). I need to import them into Oracle database vai SQL Loader.
Questions - From .txt file, I do not want to import records from 50 to 100, into Oracle database. How can I achive this?
And I want to keep Phone number colume null.

Comment: Do you have knowledge of bash scripting? With bash it's fairly easy to  skip lines and update column value

Comment: Thanks for your reply Petro. But I don't have knowledge of bash scripting.

Comment: http://www.withdata.com/oraloader/oraloader_load.html  http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Importing-text-file-to-Oracle-table  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish skipping rows 50 to 100 by using RECNUM and a WHERE clause.  You should be able to do the NULL column by either using NULLIF TRUE or making a CONSTANT generated column.  Ref: page 56 in Oracle SQL*Loader: The Definitive Guide.